# Loading xml data from url difrectly. Having trouble filtering it to only display certain fields

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-parsing, listbox, linq-to-xml

```
            var m_strFilePath = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=" + cmbLibrary.Text + "&term=" + txtProtein.Text;



        string xmlStr;
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(m_strFilePath);
        }
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

        txtblkProtein.Text = xmlStr;
        lstID.ItemsSource = xmlStr;

        lblSearch.Content = m_strFilePath;
```

That is the code I have that currently populated the textblock and the listbox from NCBI.

My problem is that the Textblock displays all of the xml data in one large cluster and the listbox displays one character per line.

This is the raw data I am working with.

https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=dystrophin

Everywhere I search to find out how to display only certain fields (like ID) with this data they assume I am formatting a local file.

Any tips or direction would be greatly appreciated, I am new to this not very knowledgable.

Thank you

Comment: The purpose of a ListBox is to display a *collection* of items. A string is a collection of characters. The ListBox displays one character per line because you gave it a string, which is a collection of characters. If you give it a collection of strings, it displays one string per line. If you give it a collection of floating point numbers, it displays one floating point number per line. Instead, you gave it a collection of characters. What did you *want* the ListBox to do?

Comment: Why are you parsing the XML and then using the unparsed string instead of the XML document you just created?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an XmlNodeReader object and load it with your XmlDocument. Then load a dataset from the the XmlNodeReader.

Once you have the data in a dataset you can manipulate/display whichever tables and columns you want.

Try this code...

```
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
XmlNodeReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
DS.ReadXml(xmlReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write XPATHs to extract the needed data

Alternatively you can also try LINQ to XML
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb387098.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You get the response as a string and assign it to `xmlStr`. Then you assign this string to the text block: `txtblkProtein.Text = xmlStr;`, so the Text is the whole response string.

Instead, you need to work with the `XmlDocument` and extract elements and attributes from there. E.g. (http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/)

Answer (score 0):

In VB Forms this would get the ID's and show them in a listbox

```
    Dim someXE As XElement

    someXE = XElement.Load("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=dystrophin") 'to load from file / uri

    lstID.Items.AddRange((From id In someXE.<IdList>.Elements Select id.Value).ToArray)
```